# Onelogin SAML implementation with other IDP that accepts SAML

Tags: c#, .net, saml, onelogin

Does the sample Onelogin SAML implementation, work with any other IDP that accepts SAML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory, it should since SAML is a standard.

But an IDP does not have to implement every part of the standard e.g. they may not implement things like artefact resolution or IDPinitiated.

So that may stop it from working.

Comment: Thanks, that helps! Is there a generic way we can SAML enable my application so that we can deploy our app for consumption in IdP app repository? We are on .Net platform end to end and mobile apps on Xamarin

Comment: You need a client-side SAML stack. Sounds like you use OneLogin but there are others - https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43. Basically, swap metadata; application -> IDP and vice versa.

Answer (score -1):

I am answering your question - is there a generic way we can SAML enable an application.... As you stated you are on .Net platform then one of the ways you could saml enable is by using a saml library provided by a third party. e.g. google search gives [ComponentPro](https://www.componentpro.com/products/saml) who provide a saml library for .net platform. Disclaimer- I have not used their product, just providing a reference.
In summary, your application will effectively become a Service Provider once it integrates with the saml library. Now your Service Provider (the .net application) can communicate with the remote IDP, Identity Provider using saml protocol. This will enable you to deploy your app (.Net app) in a IdP app repository as you stated in your question.
If you have any further questions let us know.

Comment: Stay away from ComponentPro! This "company" is a fraudster from Vietnam who stole the code for the SAML library from ComponentSpace. He is now getting sued in the US by one of the other vendors whose code he stole: https://www.pacermonitor.com/public/case/43503774/Rebex_CR_v_Dang_et_al